# How to throw many rigid bodies orderly?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I want to throw the rigid body ball like batting machine.

But i don't know how to do that. i can just throw one rigid body by using wind not keyframe.

so, is there way to throw the rigid bodies different frame like batting machine?

Answer (score 4):

The **Animated** property of [rigid bodies](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/rigid_body/properties.html#rigid-body) enables/prevents them from being simulated.

[image]

It can be keyframed as well. Start off with the animated property unchecked and key it, by hovering over the checkbox and pressing <kbd>I</kbd>. Then some frames later, when you wish for the simulation of the rigid body to start, set a keyframe with the animated property checked.

---

This can also be done with keyframes.
In this example I set LocRot keys on frame 1 and 3. Then I key the animated property to disabled on frame 2 and enabled on frame 3.

The result is a simulation starting on frame 3 with the initial velocity of frame 2.

[image: keyframes combined with rigid body dynamics]

Offset the keys as desired.

[image: nla editor, offsetting keys]